# bootstrap 3 spyscroll, tab menu and accordion anchor link smooth scrolling

Tags: tabs, anchor, accordion, smooth-scrolling

I thought, I already did it correctly, keep changing the affix in different parent div for troubleshooting, also applied and removed body's position:relative and class .nav in target item as instructed, but for tab like "our goal" or "who we serve", its content is not a lot, while i try to scroll, the page just stuck there cannot scroll down, for longer content like "leadership", it worked but the header banner just jump to the top of the window, perhaps it is matter of class .affix's top set to 0

I keep trying different value for data-offset-top also, idealy i wanted it at 0, once scrolling started it fixed to the top, but the content will jump to top, therefore i also try to set at 136 (height of header) something, but chrome doesnt seem to work, or otherwise shorter content couldnt scroll as aforementioned, but firefox is fine, i feel like banging the wall...

what thing I should take care of or the compromise i should know in these scenarios?

If in order to avoid content jump to top, i am ok to make the offset start at 136 something, but hopefully no matter what height the content is, it wont stuck cross browsers...

For anchor link smooth scroll, i searched around too, there are people mentioned that we should make the link (target item) more specify otherwise it might affect bootstrap's modal popup, but i don't know how to modify php, all the while i just copy and paste all the codes that i came across but still couldnt make it

I came across and said that bootstrap doesnt have this officially for anchor smooth scrolling, so is there any other method i can make this to those items that i want them to be smooth scrollig without affecting other bootstrap's plugins? tentatively i just removed my smootuscroll js to avoid any anchor link jumping..

homepage News & Events button (accordion)
http://sadhuism.com/work/life-care-society/

subpage tab menu 
http://sadhuism.com/work/life-care-society/who-we-are.html